# Specific IE CSS for a StudioPress Genesis Installation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, genesis

Wondering if anyone knows how to add Internet Explorer specific CSS to a Genesis installation?  I'm having some basic issues with borders and want to get around it by adding some specific IE CSS.

I'm having trouble locating where I should place my code.  I've made some changes to the child theme function.php file but I can't see anywhere to place an IE conditional.

Thanks :)

Comment: Place the conditional tags with an IE specific CSS file in whatever document contains `<head></head>`

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam, I'll have a dig for that tag..